# strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string in AdminSessionInfo

Tags: magento2

I'm using Magento ver. 2.4.3-p1

I get the following exception in the admin panel when staying away for a long time.

```
TypeError: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-security/Model/AdminSessionInfo.php:136
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-security/Model/AdminSessionInfo.php(136): strtotime()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-security/Model/AdminSessionInfo.php(119): Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionInfo->isSessionExpired()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-security/Model/AdminSessionInfo.php(108): Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionInfo->checkActivity()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-security/Model/Plugin/AuthSession.php(74): Magento\Security\Model\AdminSessionInfo->isLoggedInStatus()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Security\Model\Plugin\AuthSession->aroundProlong()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#6 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(50): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(127): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->prolong()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Index/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(245): Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Index\Interceptor->dispatch()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(212): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->getActionResponse()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(147): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#17 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/justbetter/magento2-sentry/Plugin/GlobalExceptionCatcher.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): JustBetter\Sentry\Plugin\GlobalExceptionCatcher->aroundLaunch()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#26 /var/www/html/pub/index.php(29): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run()
#27 {main}
```

I'm using the developer mode and I fix it temporarily by clearing the cookies, but is there another way to fix it permanently?

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox, clearing the cache and site data worked for me.

Comment: But that's just a workaround... Error will come again

Comment: I can confirm that using incognito tab worked when I had this error.

Answer (score 2):

issue in vendor/magento/module-security/Model/AdminSessionInfo.php
you need to replace
this

```
public function isSessionExpired()
{
    $lifetime = $this->securityConfig->getAdminSessionLifetime();
    $currentTime = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp();
    $lastUpdatedTime = $this->getUpdatedAt();
    if (!is_numeric($lastUpdatedTime)) {
        $lastUpdatedTime = strtotime($lastUpdatedTime);
    }

    return $lastUpdatedTime <= ($currentTime - $lifetime) ? true : false;
}
```

with

```
public function isSessionExpired()
{
    $lifetime = $this->securityConfig->getAdminSessionLifetime();
    $currentTime = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp();
    $lastUpdatedTime = $this->getUpdatedAt();
    if (!is_numeric($lastUpdatedTime)) {
        $lastUpdatedTime = $lastUpdatedTime === null ? 0 : strtotime($lastUpdatedTime);
    }

    return $lastUpdatedTime <= ($currentTime - $lifetime);
}
```

Comment: So do you expect that is an issue that needs to be reported to Magento?

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it. This invalidates all sessions so no login session will work

Answer (score 1):

If you have this error & you are using Adobe Commerce version there is an available quality patch to fix this

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4849817606157-MDVA-42269-Admin-user-cannot-log-into-Admin-due-to-the-TypeError-error

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Fix:

Return true if the session is blank:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Security/Model/AdminSessionInfo.php#L130

```
public function isSessionExpired()
{
    $lifetime = $this->securityConfig->getAdminSessionLifetime();
    $currentTime = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp();
    $lastUpdatedTime = $this->getUpdatedAt();
    if (empty($lastUpdatedTime)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!is_numeric($lastUpdatedTime)) {
        $lastUpdatedTime = strtotime($lastUpdatedTime);
    }

    return $lastUpdatedTime <= ($currentTime - $lifetime) ? true : false;
}
```

thanks to https://github.com/pmzandbergen:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34531#issue-1044583011

Comment: Can you please share why do we need to change the core code?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Adobe Commerce v2.4.4. A safe way is to set the lowest value for `admin/security/session_lifetime` to `60`. Then, after 60 seconds, clear redis, if used, and application cache.

No need to touch core code!

Comment: Then what? Will it solve the issue permanently, or will it only pass the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the source code may only suppress this error. The problem is that the session works not correctly. For me helps  the setting of the max_session_size_admin with the command

php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 1024000